# Is the DS version of Four Swords, different than the GBA version?

Tags: version-differences, zelda-four-swords-anniversary-ed

In this edition of Four Swords, is it different than the GBA version? Or is it the same?

Answer (score 5):

The DSiWare edition of Four Swords is changed to be playable in single-player mode. The original (a feature of the GBA port of A Link to the Past) was multiplayer-only, requiring 2-4 players to play.

Answer (score 0):

Kai said the main difference in that the DS version (anniversary edition) is playable in single-player. Other differences, [most of which are mentioned on the Wiki page:](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Four_Swords_Anniversary_Edition)

- Not paired with a game (A Link to the Past)
- Multiplayer done through DS Wireless Communications instead of link cable
- Two new stages: the Realm of Memories and the Hero's Trial, each with three doors. Each door in the Realm of Memories is based on a previous Zelda game and has more challenging puzzles compared to the other levels. The Hero's Trial is considerably more difficult than the other stages, functioning as a "hard mode." Completing these rewards the Master Sword and Hurricane Spin, respectively, which could previously only be unlocked with A Link to the Past.
- Some sound effects and tracks were improved